# DataSet in Java Web Service Client from C# Web Service

Tags: java, c#, .net, soap, dataset

I'm a novice in both Java and C#, so please bear with me.

I've made a Web Service in C# with the .Net Framework that is connected to one table in my MSSQL Server database. I've made a Java Application in Eclipse with a Web Service Client that is connected to the Web Service in Visual Studio with a SoapProxy through localhost.

The problem is that the webmethod I've made in C# is returning the Library table from MSSQL as a DataSet which I have no idea how to call as a method and print in the console of my Java Client.

Is there any better way going about the webmethod to get my table from MSSQL to VisualStudio and then printing it in my Eclipse Console?

**Java Web Service Client**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8pTz.jpg

**C# Web Service**

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WSDB : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public DataSet getBooks()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString =  "server=.;database=Library;user=sa;password=1234";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Library", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;



    }

}
```

What should the code in my Java Web Service Client look like to call and print this DataSet in the console the easiest most basic way? (formatting doesn't have to be pretty)

**Update**

I tried a different approach with a new WebMethod, connecting to my database with ADO.Net Entity Framework.

But I'm  still clueless how to call and print the method in my Java Web Client, any suggestions?

```
[WebMethod]
    public Library GetLibInfo(string booknr)
    {
        return libEnt.Libraries.Single(x=> x.booknr == booknr);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a c# programmer but from what I read about Dataset I see that is a stateful object, you should only return serializable objects from a WS.

So put your result into a simple array and return that.

Anyway you should call somethink like this:

you should have something like this:

```
WSDBLocator service = new WSDBLocator();

GetBooksReponseGetBookResults res = service.getGetBooks();

SomeKindOfCollection col = res.someMethod();
for(SomeKindOfObject o : col){
   System.out.print(o.getProperty1());
   System.out.print(",");
   System.out.print(o.getProperty2());
   System.out.print(",");
   System.out.printLn(o.getProperty3());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'm coding this as part of a project in school and I use this webmethod for 4 other Clients which makes it a pain in the ass to change the webmethod now that I'm making the last client for it.  

From what I've read it should be possible to convert a dataset to a string array and then print the array in the java console, but I'm not sure to do it exactly. Also some code samples would be awesome both for Java and C# since I'm really a beginner at this and I've been stuck at this last part for several hours now.

Answer (score 0):

If formatting isn't an issue you can just import the data from your DataTable into an object array and return it.

```
[WebMethod]
    public object[] javaCustomer()
    {
        connectCronus();  //changes the ConnectionString 
        int count = 0;
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select [Name],[City] from [CRONUS Sverige AB$Customer];");
        dt = returnDataTable();
        object[] ar = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            ar[count] = row["Name"].ToString() + "\t" + row["City"].ToString();
            count++;
        }
        return ar;
    }
```

Then it's just a matter of printing it in your java client.

```
for(Object o : proxy.javaEmployee()){
        System.out.println(o);
}
```